# JVM 64-bit different memory usages?

Tags: memory, jvm, heap-memory

I've done some reading but I'm not entirely sure about one thing, for example how much memory would this use in JVM 64 bit(sorry if stupid question, but I'm a bit confused and don't know much about this):

MyObject[] myArray; - I know an array takes up 24 bytes, but how much will each element in this array take? is every element an object reference, meaning 8 byte per element? If not, how do I know how many bytes each element in this array needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, that is when using heap sizes of less than 32 GB, the 64-bit JVM uses [compressed oops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#compressedOop) which store object pointers as a 32-bit integer (scaled by three bits when used, since all objects are aligned to 8 bytes; see the link for details), so each element would actually only use 4 bytes.

If you use more than 32 GB of heap or otherwise turn off compressed oops, however, then each element will indeed use 8 bytes.

Also, I suspect that your statement on the array header being 24 bytes is wrong. To begin with, when compressing oops, the class reference in the header is also compressed, and the identity-hash-code and array length fields are 32-bit to begin with, so I suspect it is more likely to use 12 bytes. Even when using full-length oops, it should still only take 16 bytes. I can't find any hard source verifying either, however. In general, however, it should be said that Hotspot does not even use a fixed-size object header but one that varies in size depending on various circumstances of the object. [This article](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/Synchronization) describes some of those circumstances.

That is on the Hotspot JVM, at least. Since the JLS doesn't specify any primitive sizes, it *could*, theoretically, be anything on any given JVM, though 8 bytes are, of course, the most likely implementation choice.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Will mark as answer when I can(7 minutes).

Comment: Compressed oops is enabled by default when you use heaps smaller than 32GB

Comment: @Joni: The more you know. I thought it was still just an optional feature for extra space-sensitive programs. I've edited the answer to reflect that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/array_memory_usage.shtml) is good information on how to calculate the memory usage of a Java array

For Example

let's consider a 10x10 int array. Firstly, the "outer" array has its 12-byte object header followed by space for the 10 elements. Those elements are object references to the 10 arrays making up the rows. That comes to 12+4*10=52 bytes, which must then be rounded up to the next multiple of 8, giving 56. Then, each of the 10 rows has its own 12-byte object header, 4*10=40 bytes for the actual row of ints, and again, 4 bytes of padding to bring the total for that row to a multiple of 8. So in total, that gives 11*56=616 bytes. That's a bit bigger than if you'd just counted on 10*10*4=400 bytes for the hundred "raw" ints themselves.

Comment: That article and your answer describe a 32-bit VM, however.